# Properties between Pearson correlation of two function and the correlations of their derivatives

Tags: correlation

For two functions, $f(t)$ and  $g(t)$, I can calculate the Pearson correlation $Corr$.

Does the correlation, $CorrD$, between the derivative functions,  $f'(t)$ and $g'(t)$, has some properties with $Corr$ ?

We can assume f and g are smooth (infinitely derivable)

Answer (score 0):

If you use continuous (for discrete - circular) correlation then using

FFT based representation - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Cross-correlation_theorem

correlation theorem - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation
and

differentiation properties of FFT - en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Differentiation

you could get something like this

$$ corr(f',g')=corr''(f,g) $$

But don't believe to me - I probably did something wrong - so do it yourself.